# Error C4996 received when compiling sqlite.c in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sqlite, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2013

I ported my project over from Visual Studio 2012 to 2013 and sqlite.c will not compile in it. I'm receiving this compile-time error:

```
error C4996: 'GetVersionExA': was declared deprecated
error C4996: 'GetVersionExW' was declared deprecated
```

I got the latest version of sqlite to ensure it hasn't been accounted for, but it has not. I'm not sure what to do about this error. I have made no modifications to the source; I'm simply creating a project and including sqlite.h and sqlite.c.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried compiling it with VS 2012 toolkit in VS 2013?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is because SDL check, try to **disable SDL** checks:

```
Project Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > SDL checks [set to No]
```

Comment: I had this problem yet again and referred back to this question. Thank you for identifying the source. This worked perfectly.

Comment: UPDATE: in visual studio 2015 (in community edition at least) it's VC++ instead of c/c++

Answer (score 21):

Actually C4996 is a warning, but sometimes it behaves as an error.
Anyways, you can just disable it, by using the /wd4996 compiler option, or using the pragma:

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
```

Answer (score 3):

Better than disabling warnings, you can just disable the relevant code as it is intended to be disabled by adding to the file's preprocessor defines.

Right-click on sqlite3.c, click Properties, Configuration Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor. Make sure you have "all configurations" selected for the configuration and platform dropdowns (unless you only have one platform, then just select the one that's available) and edit the Preprocessor Definitions to be

```
SQLITE_WIN32_GETVERSIONEX=0;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)
```

This will skip the `NTDDI_VERSION` check since that symbol isn't defined or is defined incorrectly when your compiler hits sqlite3.c.

There's this comment in there, too, which may be interesting:

```
/*
** NOTE: All sub-platforms where the GetVersionEx[AW] functions are
**       deprecated are always assumed to be based on the NT kernel.
*/
```

The net effect of setting that `#define` is that your OS is always assumed to be based on Win NT, which it is since you're Win 8.1 or Win 10 (or greater). ;)

So basically by disabling that warning you're just making your code slower because it needs to do work to figure out if it's on WinNT or not.

Comment: Curious to get a downvote while suggesting a method to avoid getting the warning without disabling the compiler's safety features.

Comment: This is by far the better approach, and the one I used.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem trying to use [WTL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wtl/) in a VS 2013 C++ app. Try changing the `Platform Toolset` in the `General` page of your project settings to **`Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp)`**.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I just excluded sqlite3.c and sqlite3.h from project (in Solution Explorer right click on them and select Exclude From Project) and then included again (right click on them again and select Include In Project). And now it works...

Comment: Excluding them from the project means they're removed from the Solution Explorer. How do you right click them if they're missing?
I tried doing an Add > Existing to add them back, but I get the same error.